# Limiting factors when scaling a socket.io-based web app? Simultaneous connections? Size of messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am doing livestream concerts with interactive client-side browser visuals controlled via socket.io.  As part of the performance, all users can see the position of every other user’s mouse and see a special animation when any user clicks. I want to know how well it will scale.

The client-side js tracks the user’s mouse position `{x,y}` and reports it to the server every 200ms via socket.io.  It also reports to the server whenever the user clicks `{clicking: true}`. With a follow-up report of `{clicking: false}` 100ms later.

The server receives these messages and updates a global state object that contains `{x,y,clicking}` for every user.  It broadcasts this global state to all users every 33ms.

(Its also tracking a LOT of other user interactions, so this question is not about mouse tracking per se--this is just a subset/example for simplicity of scaling discussion.)

I’m currently using a Heroku Free Tier Web Dyno, and the visuals are performing perfectly for up to 60 live viewers. But I have no idea how it will scale.

#### As my audience grows, what will be the limiting factor for the project in terms of server performance?

The number of concurrent users? The size of the JSON object being sent? The number of overall messages being sent?  Will the heroku server specs be the limiting factor? And if so, what should I prioritize in a new server setup to scale efficiently?  Ideally I would like to know when I’m approaching the limits of my current setup so I don’t risk having the server crash or lag heavily during a promoted event.

Comment: Easiest way might be write to a client that abuses the protocol. Maybe get some EC2 instances to run a few thousand clients. On Heruko, I suspect bandwidth will be a problem since you're using the free tier. They don't say how much throughput you get, just that you're capped at 2TB/month, and their typical use case doesn't seem geared to high-throughput workloads.

Comment: @Ouroborus This is an excellent idea!  THANK YOU! I'm going to start figuring out how to make that happen today.  (If I get any analysis useful for others I'll post it here!) Out of curiosity, if you were leading this project and Heroku turned out to be the limiting factor, what alternative would you use?  What IS designed for high-throughput workloads?  (Sorry if that's a n00b question--never attempted to scale a project like this! Thanks for the handhold!)

Comment: I'm not sure any of them are specifically designed for high throughput. But both AWS and Google Cloud have had the market pressure to incidentally have large bandwidth available. I find AWS to be more flexible and Google Cloud to have better pings. But keep in mind that my use-cases haven't been like what you're attempting and that there are lot of cloud service providers out there.